# C# - Put window code in a class (code obfuscation)

Tags: c#, class, window, obfuscation

This is probably a silly and confusing question but should I be putting my C# code in a class file and then referencing it into the window file code rather than putting it directly into the window file code? **Bearing in mind I want to obfuscate my code afterwards.**

Example of putting code directly into window file:

(MainWindow)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
      //Do Some Code
    }
```

Example of putting code in a class and referencing it to MainWindow:

(MainWindow)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Helper.DoButton1Code();
}
```

(Helper class)

```
 public static bool DoButton1Code()
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
      //Do Some Code
    }
```

Comment: You want to know if having the code in a different class is better for obfuscation or in general?

Comment: No, I'm currently putting my code in the window file and not using classes. Do I need to put it into classes like in my example above in order to obfuscate my project?

Comment: Then no, there is no difference, just put it in the windows file (which, by the way, is a class). Be also aware that even if obfuscated, your code can be reverse engineered (albeit with with some more difficulty).

Comment: So can I use SmartAssembly obfuscator on window form code as well as blank class code?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it does not make much difference where you put your logic or resource (e.g. string), as long as it is obfuscated. You should however focus on organizing your code such that it is easier for you to debug and maintain.

Using reflector.exe etc., however we can see your public method signature, though the function name might be obfuscated.

Comment: Will I be able to obfuscate my code using SmartAssembly whether it's placed in the Window Form code or in classes then?